# Using EEVEE for interactive VR presentations?

Tags: game-engine, eevee-render-engine

Does anyone know if it is possible (or future plans) to use eevee to make interactive architectural VR-presentations? I have customers who want VR and need to change my pipeline.

I understand I can model things in Blender (which I am starting to like very much) and export everything to Unreal Engine 4 for the rest of the workflow. As I need to handle changes in the building models right up to my deadlines, I would prefer staying in just one application.

Can I hope to do this in Blender?

Comment: I think this is the best answer: http://gph.is/1KxUnD4 It's not sure if EEVEE will be merged to Blender Game Engine, there is proposal: https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2017-July/048473.html and there is https://blendervr.limsi.fr/doku.php for VR in BGE. So let's stick to the first link for now.

Comment: This works but it seems it's dead and needs an old oculus sdk https://github.com/dfelinto/virtual_reality_viewport

Answer (score 2):

https://godotengine.org/

I think you might be better served using Blender to prepare your assets, but then use Godot Engine for the actual deployment.

Here's a recent video with a bunch of games showcasing Godot's power and versatility:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTAeDoRIHaA

Here's a video of Godot 3 new features:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XptlVErsL-o

Godot is an open-source, modern, PBR-based Game Engine that can export executables for all major desktop and mobile operating systems, and also for HTML5. It also has a nice audio engine so you could add 3D audio with reverb zones etc. to increase the immersion of your presentation.

You could prepare your interactive demonstration, and host it on a website and let the client view it on-line or deliver an elegant Windows/OS X/Linux executable.

Godot has all the great features of a modern rendering engine you'd find in Eevee, but is a bit more robust on that front and it have been used to build quite a lot of games at this point. The PBR engine is a relatively new addition but seems to be working very well.

Godot works very nice with Blender-made assets. You can use COLLADA to export your models from Blender and Godot will automatically reload them once you re-export an updated version from Blender. I've even read somewhere it's possible to export PBR materials with textures in COLLADA from Blender right into Godot - haven't tested that too well myself though.

Godot also provides an improved COLLADA exporter for Blender.

Comment: Blender 2.8 is due a while from now but it will introduce interactivity see [here](https://twitter.com/blender_org/status/1001110824012967936)

Comment: Thanks, @Sidar ! I'm glad to hear they want to provide better integration with other game engines as well.